# Word meaning to aggregate/agglomerate into two opposing elements

Tags: single-word-requests

I am seeking a word describing when a system of many elements agglomerates
into two opposing or differing elements.

Similar to *dichotomize, polarize, bifurcate,* but going from many to two, not
one to two (or, maybe there is more general terminology for bidirectional).

I don’t mind borrowing specialized terminology from some domain – let’s
hear them!

Comment: Why don't you like 'polarize'? One thing doesn't polarize: but (for example) the opinions of a group of many people can polarize at extremes.

Comment: Like oil and vinegar separating? Or like someone deciding which are the small potatoes and which are the big?

Comment: A system of many elements that divides into two separate and opposite parts? Makes me think of physics and particles.

Comment: It does this by itself, or are people controlling the sorting?

Comment: @Lambie yes, I immediately thought of strange attractors because it sounds like the system does this by itself.

Comment: @WeatherVane I suppose polarize is the closest - I was using political party formation as the context, imagining many interest groups needing to aggregate over time in the pursuit of survival. I was not thinking of its meaning as starting from a single whole - good point.

Comment: @PhilSweet since I was using political party formation as the context, I imagined a system seeking this state due to feedback loops, intra-system conflict.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a single word request and the poster has not given the sentence in which they wish to use the word. Absent context, answers will be guesses.

Comment: You *could* steal **bicluster aggregation** from data mining because it kinda sounds like it should mean what you want. The *bi* there doesn't refer to two clusters, but to data aggregation on both rows and columns of data simultaneously. You'd only confuse people with a foot in each domain. (I'm not posting this as an answer because it really isn't. It's a suggested neologism in this domain.)

Comment: Would neither 'boil down to' nor 'resolve into' work? 

Either way, in my view word, phrase or expression requests should be promoted to their own specialised community, perhaps named 'Vocabulary.'

Answer (score 0):

A term I know that would work for this (if I've understood your goal) is to *partition* the set [into two or more subsets according to some criterion or criteria].

Also, there are nouns, *partition* and *partitioning*: *We will apply the algorithm to the two subsets resulting from the partitioning carried out in Step 1."

Here's a definition of the verb:

> 8. to divide into parts or portions.  (Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010)

I found this at the [freedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/partition).